# How To Perform Secure Image Upload Using MIME Instead Of Allowed File Types Which Detects Image Extension Only

Tags: php

I have written a php script which checks the image file for its extension, such as JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, uploaded through an HTML form.

Now comes my problem: anyone may upload any kind of file by giving it an extension of JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF.

Can someone help me on that? One should strictly be able to upload only an image file and not any other file which carries just extension of Image file.

I tried hard... but failed... Here is the php script I have written
**CHECK MY FULL CODE I HAVE WRITTEN & ITS WORKING FINE BUT WHEN I CHANGE ANY FILE EXTENSION WITH IMAGE EXTENSION ITS ALLOWING UPLOAD ON SERVER WHICH IS NOT SERCURE PLEASE SEE THIS FULL CODE AND ADD SOLUTION , THIS WILL HELP OTHERS TOO -THANK YOU https://www.dropbox.com/s/prza75dyo7usjqy/secure%20image%20upload%20with%20checking%20extension.txt?dl=0**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))

    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
    $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $allowed_file_types = array('.jpg','.png','.jpeg','.gif');  
    
    //instead of allowed file type i want to check image authenticity with MIME

    if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 100000))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php) API, which makes you able to check a file MIME content-type by looking at its bytes, not its name.

An image MIME type always starts with `image/`, for example `image/png`.

```php
$finfo = new finfo();
$mimeType = $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

$isImage = strpos($mimeType, 'image/') === 0;
```

If you want to be very restrictive on your allowed images, check the [list of available MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#Image_types).

**Edit: be more specific**

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif');
    $finfo = new finfo();
    $mimeType = $finfo->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $isImage = in_array($mimeType, $allowed_file_types);

    if ($isImage && $filesize < 100000) {
```

Comment: Please Answer In Above Code Context, how can i apply this code to upper one please specify

Comment: I have edited it. Note that I use the `tmp_name` key to retrieve the filename on server side, not `name` which is client side.

Comment: sir not working check my full code and add solution to it https://www.dropbox.com/s/prza75dyo7usjqy/secure%20image%20upload%20with%20checking%20extension.txt?dl=0

Comment: hope you're kidding, buddy :) i'm not here to do your job. This piece of code is _working_, even if you say it does _not_. Remember when you asking me to _specify_ ?

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to check if something is *really* an image, is to open the file as an image and then re-generate it.

Things that are valid images can still carry loads of other information and sometimes can trick whatever is reading it. So the most safe thing is to take the pixels from the image, and regenerate it.

Extensions like `fileinfo` only check the first few bytes for a marker, but it's not 100% reliable. It might be good enough for you

Comment: I hesitated between my current answer and an another one looking like your steps, with `Imagick` API but since it appears to me to be a beginner question and given the tiny size of `fileinfo` compared to `Imagick`, I've chosen `fileinfo`.

Comment: @rugolinifr yea i figured this is a good question that can have 2 valid answers =)